# Can I bind the selection in a SwiftUI Table to Item instead of Item.ID?

Tags: swiftui, selection

I have a SwiftUI Table whose rows are populated by FetchedResults.
To be able to trigger a detail pane view to show the item of the selected table row I want to map the table selection to an enum in a coordinator class.

In a list I could map it directly like this:

```
List(collectionEntries, id: \.self, selection: $coordinator.detailDisplay)
```

Because the selection in tables tracks IDs I have to do it like this ATM. Is there a simpler way for tables?

```
struct CollectionTable: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    
    let collectionEntries: FetchedResults<CollectionEntry>
    
    @State private var selected = Set<CollectionEntry.ID>()
    
    @ObservedObject var coordinator = NavigationCoordinator.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Table(collectionEntries, selection: $selected) {
            TableColumn("Name") { entry in
                Text(entry.name ?? "n/a")
            }
            TableColumn("Type") { entry in
                Text(entry..type ?? "n/a")
            }
            TableColumn("Language") { entry in
                Text(entry.lang ?? "n/a")
            }
            TableColumn("Price") { entry in
                Text(entry.price_usd.description ?? "n/a")
            }
            TableColumn("Count") { entry in
                Text(entry.count.description)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selected) { newValue in
            guard let selectedEntry = collectionEntries.first(where: { entry in
                entry.id == newValue.first!
            }) else {
                return
            }
            coordinator.detailDisplay = .entry(selectedEntry)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to go down this path when I found your question. I'm a little dismayed that you've gotten no answer. Did you ever figure anything out?

That Apple's example program doesn't actually do anything with the selection is kind of sad. I'm starting to think their Table is not ready for much of anything.

Comment: @HackSaw No, I implemented it exactly like this. I wouldn't say Table is not ready for much of anything, but it certainly seems to be a bit behind the more iOS focused widgets.

Comment: I ended up using .onChange to update a @State variable when the selection changed, and then a normal if $selection != nil { view0fThingy(selectedItem } sort of thing. Feels pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Use contextMenu's [primary action](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(forselectiontype:menu:primaryaction:))

```
.contextMenu(forSelectionType: Item.ID.self) { items in
    // ...
} primaryAction: { items in
    for item in items {
        openWindow(value: item)
    }
}
```